# CoreData Lightweight Migration fails when changing Entity Name in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data

**Context**

I use `CoreData` and and encountered a problem with `Lightweight Migration`. I had an `Entity` called `Examination` which I successfully renamed to `Exam` a few Model Versions earlier. I also have an Entity called `ExaminationNew`, which I would like to rename to `Examination` now.

---

**Steps**

1. I created a new `Model Version`
2. I set the new `Model Version` as active
3. I renamed `ExaminationNew` to `Examination` and set the `Renaming Identifier` of it to "ExaminationNew"

> When running this, I get the following error: `SQLite error code:1, 'table ZEXAM already exists'`. Please note, that the `Renaming Identifier` of `Exam` is not set in the new `Model Version`

---

**Question**

- What causes this behaviour and how can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the coredata by replacing names like as you already used this name before for a table

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII that's what I thought, too. However, I can't imagine how. Why is `CoreData` trying to create a new `Exam` table when I am only changing `ExaminationNew` to `Examination`?

Comment: The renaming identifier in the current xcd data model entity should be set.It should be the name of the entity in the previous Data model.